# Why do the Merged Category links in footer not combine categories?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, user-interface, footer

The new footer has 5 current "Boxes" of categories: Technology, Life/Arts, Culture/Recreation, Science, and Other.

In the [overall site list](https://stackexchange.com/sites#), however, there are 7 (discounting Business / All), with Life/Arts and Culture/Recreation being split up into their individual "Boxes".

However, clicking the "More" link of the site footer always brings you to the first "box", so Life or Culture.

The issue I just ran into was that it's not obvious that the boxes are merged on the footer and split on the site list. I clicked the "More" link for Culture/Recreation, and then spent a good several minutes looking for a Recreation site in the culture tab.

There are two main issues here:

- The combined Culture/Recreation and Life/Arts lists do not show which of the two categories the listed sites fall under. (Is Photography Life or Art? Is Travel Culture or Recreation?)
- The sites are grouped differently on the footer and in the site list.

I think if you're going to bundle the categories on the footer, you should do it on the sites list as well.

Comment: Yes, we plan on doing that, but for the initial release of the new footer, we wanted to get the new and improved out there as soon as possible.

Comment: @Oded why not multiple "more" links e.g. "more Culture" and "more Recreation"? Sounds like reasonable solution to me, saving the need to change the sites list or change the footer design yet again..

Comment: @Oded Are their also plans to add site icons to the footer? Right now, the new footer looks like a big bland block of text.

Comment: @RavenDreamer - Not that I am aware of. If you mean the colored squares - I don't think we will see them back.

Comment: @Raven I think most people (myself included) find the current design more clean, we don't need colors and icons in the footer.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - We are still looking at the different options on how the footers can cleanly integrate with se.com/sites

Comment: @Oded cheers, let the best option win! :-)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Well, to each their own, I suppose. [In my case...](http://xkcd.com/1172/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We joined up the categories on stackexchange.com to match up with the new footer.

Clicking the "more" links for the columns with two categories will show the relevant section now.